# How to authorize access to directory using nginx auth_request module + python

Tags: python, nginx, authorization, auth-request

I want to authorize access to directory `/private` using `auth_request` Nginx module .

In [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html) , it seems I should do like bellow :

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

    location /private/{
            auth_request /auth;
    }

    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    }
}
```

In my case `http://localhost:8080/` is a python server, which should authenticate users against database. here is the python code :

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        print(str(self.request))
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(403) # just test
    def get(self):
        print(str(self.request))
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(401) # test also


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Now, when I visit `http://localhost/private/` in the browser it prints :

pending on my code it returns

```
401 Authorization Required
```

**Question :** how do I request / receive username, and password data, so I could raise 401 exception or let the user pass?